# Estimate an upper and lower bounds about $\int\limits_0^1$ $\frac{x^n}{1+x^n} dx$

Tags: calculus, inequality

Why are the inequations true?

$\frac{1}{2(1+n)}$ $\leq$ $\int\limits_0^1$ $\frac{x^n}{1+x^n} dx $ $\leq$ $\frac{1}{(1+n)}$

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: For $x \in (0,1)$ we have $$\frac{x^n}{1+x^n} \leq x^n$$ and $$ \frac{x^n}{1+x^n} \geq \frac{x^n}{2}$$